# Sharepoint Import command - Import List in same site collection

Tags: powershell, restore

I have a sitecollection with list name "XYZ" and 5million records , I exported the list using the PS command . How to import the backed up sharepoint list"XYZ" under the same site collection : Command not working : `Import-SPWeb -Identity https://site.com/Conssstsdd -path C:\nikhil\backup.cmp` .

Something like this:[Is there a way to duplicate or copy a list into the same site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/97687/is-there-a-way-to-duplicate-or-copy-a-list-into-the-same-site)

Comment: what are the export command you use?

Comment: Export-SPWeb http://site.com/Conssstsdd/abc -ItemUrl "/abc/Lists/ListName" -Path "C:\nikhil\backup.cmp"

Comment: try this one Export-SPWeb http://site -Path "C:\nikhil\backup.cmp"

Comment: Dont you think this will backup the entire site instead of only the list ?

Comment: what you want, which backup you want List, Site or Site collection?

Comment: above will export the entire list

Comment: :) only the list backup and restore in same site collection

Comment: did you try to export from the Central admin? under backup and restore section.http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428301(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: why don't you do it via gui? list settings save as template, with content and then create the list on the new place from this template?

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to import the list under the same site with the same name you can use `-force` which forcefully **overwrites if it already exists**.

NB. This will overwrite what is currently there.

Comment: No ways , i dont want to overwrite the existing list . i want a copy .

Comment: Ok, it wasn't clear above. Take a look at this powershell script looks like it will do what you require [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4990.sharepoint-2010-how-to-copy-a-list-using-powershell-script.aspx)

I think the import-spweb may be failing due to the amount of content<?>